# Ruby execution order in multithreaded program

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In prep for hurricane irma I wrote a quick trash script to download a bunch of exercises off exercism.io. It works, but there's an error at the call to `threads.each` that I don't understand, all the code up until threads.each is synchronous if I understand correctly, so I'm not sure what the best way to fix is.:

`rb:14:in '<main>': undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

It's interesting to me because I get the error but the program still runs as expected, so I'm sure I'm not writing this properly.

```
language = ARGV[0]

exercises = `exercism list #{@language}`.split("\n")

threads = exercises.map do |exercise|
  break if exercise == ''

  Thread.new do
    system("exercism fetch #{language} #{exercise}")
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next` instead of `break` so that `threads` is still set if any exercises are blank. `break` will cancel the whole loop, but `next` will skip only the current iteration.

Then some threads could still be `nil` if their exercise is blank, because no thread has started for them. You can use `threads.compact.each(&:join)` to skip these `nil` values.

Or if you need the `break`, then add to `threads` inside the loop like:

```
threads = []
exercises.each do |exercise|
  break if exercise == ''

  threads << Thread.new do
    system("exercism fetch #{language} #{exercise}")
  end
end
```

Comment: In this specific case I know that once we hit `""`, there are no more exercises, it's just instructions after that.

Comment: @NoobException `break` will prevent the assignment to `threads` from taking place, so you'd need to replace it with `next`, or get rid of the assignment, and append to threads within the loop instead.

Comment: But your comment about appending in the loop does make sense, if you answer I'll mark it as correct.